# Expanding the row based on comma and map to another row in pandas python

Tags: pandas

I have input dataset like the first image. I want to map the columns to one other. I want the output in format given in second image. If I explode the columns it is showing both values. What is the accurate way to do this?
[image: Suppose I have input like this]

[image: I want the output to be like another image using pandas]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please [don't post images of code/data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) instead add them in text format so that we could be able to copy these while trying to answer the question. Please take some time to read [How to ask good pandas questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

print(
    pd.DataFrame(
        df.apply(lambda x: [*zip_longest(*x, fillvalue=np.nan)], axis=1)
        .explode()
        .to_list(),
        columns=df.columns,
    )
)
```

Prints:

```
     A  B
0  abc  1
1  NaN  2
2  pqr  3
3  xyz  4
```

Comment: Thanks. That is really helpful.